# Using jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut on an element scrumbles its positioning

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have an element that is shown or hidden depending on some condition. 
I use jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut() animations to hide or show the element.

My problem is that the positioning of that element is suddenly changed after a fadeOut/fadeIn sequence. However I cannot find any difference in the computed style rules. Neither for the element itself nor for the embedding div tag. 
What is changed after the sequence ?

I made a short test case: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2QVX8/14/

Note the triangle below the table pointing down, it is centered. When you click the "toggle" button twice the fadeOut/fadeIn sequence is run. Afterwards the element is not centered any more but positioned hard left.

Here is the code of the test case:

HTML:

```
<button id='toggle'>Toggle</button>
<p/>
<div>
      <table id="list">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>1-1</td><td>1-2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2-1</td><td>2-2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3-1</td><td>3-2</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div id="footer">
          <span>&#9662;</span>
      </div>
</div>
​
```

CSS:

```
table{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;   
}
table tr td{
  text-align: center;  
}
#footer{
  position: absolute;
}
```

​JS/jQuery:

```
$('#toggle').bind('click',function(){
    if ($('#footer span').is(':visible'))
       $('#footer span').fadeOut('fast');   
  else $('#footer span').fadeIn('fast');   
})
```

Comment: WHAT is: `<p>` without a closure! and what is: `</tr></tr>` ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, too much in a hurry. I corrected those glitches, they have nothing to do with the original problem. Thanks !

Comment: No problem. I fixed your issue with just a bit of CSS take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand why, but an absolute position without coordinates will make it unstable. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/2QVX8/15/

Comment: Yep, just realized that too. See my own Answer to this issue: I removed the absolute positioning and all is fine.

Comment: Although all other answers solve the problem as well I accept this answer because it is the only one that actually explains _why_ the absolute positioning is a problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
#footer span{
     position: relative;
}
```

Comment: You suppress the effect in the test case. This is a workaround that changes the layout to get the desired effect in this test case. Works here, but is no general solution or answer to the question. The test case is a simplified version of my real world problem. In there I have an img tag, not a span. I cannot set an img to width:100%;. I used a span tag in the test case to keep things simple. Too simple maybe, sorry for that. The question still is: where is the difference between before and after the sequence has run ?

Comment: @arkascha Reedited my answer. Sorry for not interpreting well your thoughts.

Comment: The difference is that your element is opened at the beginning, and due to text-align the children is being floated center. But once the element faded out you loose the text-alignment cause there's no room for elements that have no relative position (relative to parent) set, or at least a width 100% that will maintain it's size inside the faded parent.

Comment: we thought into the same direction: in the Answer I gave myself inbetween I also removed the absolute positioning. That works. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/2QVX8/18/

HTML :

```
<button id='toggle'>Toggle</button>
<p>
<div>
      <table id="list">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>1-1</td><td>1-2</tr></tr>
            <tr><td>2-1</td><td>2-2</tr></tr>
            <tr><td>3-1</td><td>3-2</tr></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div id="footer">
          <div class="arrow">&#9662;</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;   
}
table tr td{
  text-align: center;  
}

#footer{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#toggle').bind('click',function(){
    if ($('#footer .arrow').is(':visible'))
       $('#footer .arrow').fadeOut('fast');   
  else $('#footer .arrow').fadeIn('fast');   
})
```

Comment: You fade the container instead of the element. I do not want to do this, because this has other layout issues apart from this question. I need to keep the container. Sorry.

Comment: Hm, am I missing something ? The only change I can spot is that you use a class instead of an id selector. But why does it work then ? What is the difference behind it ? I would expect the same modifications to be applied, since the selectors produce the same set of elements.

Comment: Ah, now I just see that you also removed the absolute positioning from the span. This is the solutions we others also came to. Using a class selector instead of an id selector has nothing to do with the solution . Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is probably the most simple solution:

I remove the absolute css positioning rule for the footer:

```
position:absolute;
```

See the [fidler](http://jsfiddle.net/2QVX8/20/), unchanged apart from that change: